# Calculating relations between two fields in single layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, fields-attributes

I have a layer with a field named prog_num and another field named land_use. Each program number has a number of different type of land use assigned.

I want to have a record for each program number - what are the land uses for each program and the number of them.

Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS Pro? I have tried summary statistics but it only works on a single field. I need the data per program number and not as chart of land uses total count.

What I am trying to get is similar of what you can do with a pivot in Excel. I cant use Excel because there are 60,000 records.

The SQL syntax in Pro is not an open syntax so I cannot use SQL.

I don't know Python nor Arcade - can it be done with another tool?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, you seem to have missed the Tour's emphasis on One question per Question. If the title has an "and" in it, there's a good chance the Question will attract close votes. Please [Edit] the Question (and title) to focus on one question. Note that "is it possible" questions should instead focus on "How can I..." and "I tried..."

Comment: BTW, it you search on the words you used in the Question (" ArcGIS summarize statistics"), you may well locate your answer.

Comment: Summary Statistics works on a list of stats and a list of case fields, so the "only works on a single field" is incorrect. You should probably focus this on your Summary Statistics issue instead of asking for a different tool.